# Сортировка строк в текстовом файле php (запись в файл)

Tags: php, массивы, строки, сортировка

Есть текстовый файл temp6.txt в котором строки располагаются не по порядку. Сортировку я выполняю следующим образом:

```
$arr_temp = file("temp6.txt");
$save = fopen("temp66.txt", "a+");
rsort($arr_temp);
$result = "";
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($arr_temp); $i++ ) {
$result .= trim($arr_temp[$i])."\n";
}
fwrite($save, $result);
fclose($save);
```

На страницу сайта строки выводятся отсортированными в порядке убывания (у каждой строки вначале стоит число), запись в файл temp66.txt тоже осуществляется корректно. 
Нужно, чтобы результат сортировки записывался в исходный файл temp6.txt 
Если в `$save = fopen("temp66.txt", "a+");`temp66.txt поменять на temp6.txt то в temp6.txt окажутся строки ДО сортировки и следом отсортированные строки. А нужно, чтобы были ТОЛЬКО отсортированные.

Comment: Юленька, параметры у функций придуманы не для красоты, а для выполнения определенных действий. Уточнить действие каждого параметра можно в документации. В частности, по ссылке http://php.net/fopen можно прочесть, что параметр "a+" означает, что в temp6.txt окажутся строки ДО сортировки и следом отсортированные строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему в файле temp6.txt можно найти сперва несортированные, а потом сортированные строки - как тебе уже подсказали проблема в аргументе `a+` функции `fopen` в попытке перезаписать изначальный файл `$save = fopen("temp66.txt", "a+")`, этот параметр означает что данные будут добавляться к содержимому файла без удаления старых.

Самое важное - в большинстве случаев **не стоит** использовать запись сразу в файл, из которого идёт чтение, потому что в случае ошибки можно потерять данные. Лучше сперва выполнить запись в файл temp66.txt - `$save = fopen("temp66.txt", "w");`, убедиться что данные корректны и только потом записать данные в изначальный файл temp6.txt.

И определенно не будет лишним внимательно почитать про аргументы функции fopen и остальные функции открытия файлов и записи [в документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.filesystem.php)

Comment: видимо у меня как раз всё было вверх ногами из-за записи сразу в файл. Записывая в новый - всё работает хорошо. Продумаю, как можно сократить число неверсионных файлов. Спасибо за совет.) @Ярослав

Comment: @Юленька, вообще если вероятность ошибки практически исключена(например, файлы имеют строго один формат и если успешно обработался один - обработаются все другие) в целом можно использовать запись из файла в тот же файл сразу. Только при этом надо иметь в виду что брать информацию из файла надо сразу единым куском и записывать без переоткрывания файла в цикле. 
Иначе можно поймать ситуацию когда, например, при построчном чтении 1. Считалась первая строка 2. Обработалась 3. Изначальный файл очистился, записалась первая строка обработанная. Всё кроме неё исчезло. И таких узких мест - множество.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_temp = file("temp6.txt");
rsort($arr_temp);
$result = "";

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($arr_temp); $i++ ) {
   $result .= trim($arr_temp[$i])."\n";
}

file_put_contents('temp6.txt',$result);
```

попробуй использовать file_put_contents она перезапишет имеющийся фаил.